SignalR ECS container unable to connect to RDS postgres database from task
I am trying to set up a signalR hub on a ECS task with EC2 type. For some reason no matter what I do I can not connect to my data base. I get this error:
June 11, 2024 at 14:37 (UTC-5:00)   fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]  
June 11, 2024 at 14:37 (UTC-5:00)   An error occurred using the connection to database '<database name>' on server 'tcp://<servername>'.    
June 11, 2024 at 14:37 (UTC-5:00)   info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10404]   talkwaveapi
June 11, 2024 at 14:37 (UTC-5:00)   A transient exception occurred during execution. The operation will be retried after 0ms.   
June 11, 2024 at 14:37 (UTC-5:00)   Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Failed to connect to 10.0.2.227:5432

Here is my task definition
{
    "family": "TalkWaveApiTask",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "talkwaveapi",
            "image": "<image>",
            "cpu": 700,
            "memory": 700,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "talkwaveapi-8080-tcp",
                    "containerPort": 8080,
                    "hostPort": 8080,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "appProtocol": "http"
                },
                {
                    "name": "postgres",
                    "containerPort": 5432,
                    "hostPort": 5432,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "appProtocol": "http"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "CONNECTIONSTRINGS__DEFAULTCONNECTION",
                    "value": "Server=<server name>;Port=5432;Database=<db name>;Username=postgres;password=<password>"
                }
            ],
            "environmentFiles": [
                {
                    "value": "arn:aws:s3:::talkwave-signalr-env/.env",
                    "type": "s3"
                }
            ],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/TalkWaveApiTask",
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-east-2",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                },
                "secretOptions": []
            },
            "healthCheck": {
                "command": [
                    "CMD-SHELL",
                    "curl --fail http://localhost:8080/health || exit 1"
                ],
                "interval": 60,
                "timeout": 10,
                "retries": 3,
                "startPeriod": 300
            },
            "systemControls": []
        }
    ],
    "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::584742206045:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::584742206045:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "EC2"
    ],
    "runtimePlatform": {
        "cpuArchitecture": "X86_64",
        "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
    }
}

Here is my docker image
COPY TalkWaveApi.WebSocket.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build app
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c release -o /app

# final stage/image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app ./
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 5432

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y curl

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TalkWaveApi.WebSocket.dll"]

And what my db context builder looks like
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options =>
options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), x =>
{
    x.MigrationsHistoryTable("_EfMigrations", Configuration.GetSection("Schema").GetSection("TalkwaveDataSchema").Value);
    x.EnableRetryOnFailure();
}));

I've ran reachability analysis and it came back good between the EC2 instances and the RDS database. The security groups allow inbound and outbound connections between the EC2 and RDS. This is on a private VPC. I also ran the container locally and it worked fine. I'm out of ideas on what to try next. All health checks are passing (load balancer and ECS). Other services (lambda) are able to connect to the exact same database with the connection string.
Edit: More logs
June 11, 2024 at 20:08 (UTC-5:00)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TState,TResult](Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  ba2c2d3d3e104590b152dcb3efcd7bd0    talkwaveapi
June 11, 2024 at 20:08 (UTC-5:00)   Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Failed to connect to 10.0.2.227:5432   ba2c2d3d3e104590b152dcb3efcd7bd0    talkwaveapi
June 11, 2024 at 20:08 (UTC-5:00)   ---> System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.  ba2c2d3d3e104590b152dcb3efcd7bd0    talkwaveapi
June 11, 2024 at 20:08 (UTC-5:00)   at Npgsql.TaskTimeoutAndCancellation.ExecuteAsync(Func`2 getTaskFunc, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   ba2c2d3d3e104590b152dcb3efcd7bd0    talkwaveapi
June 11, 2024 at 20:08 (UTC-5:00)   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.ConnectAsync(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) ba2c2d3d3e104590b152dcb3efcd7bd0    talkwaveapi
June 11, 2024 at 20:08 (UTC-5:00)   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.ConnectAsync(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) ba2c2d3d3e104590b152dcb3efcd7bd0    talkwaveapi
June 11, 2024 at 20:08 (UTC-5:00)   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)  ba2c2d3d3e104590b152dcb3efcd7bd0    talkwaveapi
June 11, 2024 at 20:08 (UTC-5:00)   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>g__OpenCore|213_1(NpgsqlConnector conn, SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)    ba2c2d3d3e104590b152dcb3efcd7bd0    talkwaveapi
June 11, 2024 at 20:08 (UTC-5:00)   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  ba2c2d3d3e104590b152dcb3efcd7bd0    talkwaveapi
June 11, 2024 at 20:08 (UTC-5:00)   at Npgsql.PoolingDataSource.OpenNewConnector(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  ba2c2d3d3e104590b152dcb3efcd7bd0    talkwaveapi
June 11, 2024 at 20:08 (UTC-5:00)   at Npgsql.PoolingDataSource.<Get>g__RentAsync|34_0(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    ba2c2d3d3e104590b152dcb3efcd7bd0    talkwaveapi
June 11, 2024 at 20:08 (UTC-5:00)   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<Open>g__OpenAsync|42_0(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  ba2c2d3d3e104590b152dcb3efcd7bd0    talkwaveapi
June 11, 2024 at 20:08 (UTC-5:00)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    ba2c2d3d3e104590b152dcb3efcd7bd0    talkwaveapi
June 11, 2024 at 20:08 (UTC-5:00)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    ba2c2d3d3e104590b152dcb3efcd7bd0    talkwaveapi
June 11, 2024 at 20:08 (UTC-5:00)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)    ba2c2d3d3e104590b152dcb3efcd7bd0    talkwaveapi
June 11, 2024 at 20:08 (UTC-5:00)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    ba2c2d3d3e104590b152dcb3efcd7bd0    talkwaveapi
June 11, 2024 at 20:08 (UTC-5:00)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   ba2c2d3d3e104590b152dcb3efcd7bd0    talkwaveapi
June 11, 2024 at 20:08 (UTC-5:00)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass30_0`2.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() ba2c2d3d3e104590b152dcb3efcd7bd0    talkwaveapi
June 11, 2024 at 20:08 (UTC-5:00)   --- End of stack trace from previous location ---   ba2c2d3d3e104590b152dcb3efcd7bd0    talkwaveapi
June 11, 2024 at 20:08 (UTC-5:00)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TState,TResult](Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  ba2c2d3d3e104590b152dcb3efcd7bd0    talkwaveapi
June 11, 2024 at 20:08 (UTC-5:00)   dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20000]  ba2c2d3d3e104590b152dcb3efcd7bd0    talkwaveapi
June 11, 2024 at 20:08 (UTC-5:00)   Opening connection to database 'TalkWave' on server 'tcp://<db connection>:'.


Your ECS task has awsvpc network mode, which means it gets it's own Elastic Network Interface and its own security group assignment. It does not use the network connection of the EC2 instance. You need to make sure the database instance allows traffic from the ECS tasks's security gruop.
